# Implementing a join in doctrine query builder not working correctly

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I am trying to get information from one table based on information in another table, which is linked by an ID.

The two tables are: `property` and `unit`.

I need to gather all the units within a property but ONLY if the property has a status of '1' and a hidden flag of '0'. In normal mySQL, I wrote:

```
SELECT u.* FROM unit u INNER JOIN property p ON p.id = u.property WHERE p.status = 1 AND p.hidden = 0
```

which produces the correct results, although when I try the same using querybuilder:

```
$qb = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder();
$qb->select('u')
    ->from('AppBundle:Unit', 'u')
    ->join('u', 'AppBundle:Property', 'p', 'u.property = p.id')
    ->where('p.status = :status')
    ->andWhere('p.hidden = :hidden')
    ->setParameter('status', 1)
    ->setParameter('hidden', 0);

return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
```

Using information I gleaned from the Doctrine Query Builder documentation. However, when I load the page I get the following error:

> [Semantical Error] line 0, col 42 near 'u AppBundle:Property': Error:
>   Class 'u' is not defined.

The query being executed:

```
SELECT u FROM AppBundle:Unit u INNER JOIN u AppBundle:Property P u.property = p.id WHERE p.status = :status AND p.hidden = :hidden
```

Can anyone help figure out what I'm doing wrong in my query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to change this:

```
->join('u', 'AppBundle:Property', 'p', 'u.property = p.id')
```

to this:

```
->join('AppBundle:Property', 'p', 'WITH', 'u.property = p.id')
```

Answer (score 0):

You should exchange your first and second arguments places, because join() method is:

```
/**
 * Creates and adds a join over an entity association to the query.
 *
 * The entities in the joined association will be fetched as part of the query
 * result if the alias used for the joined association is placed in the select
 * expressions.
 *
 * <code>
 *     $qb = $em->createQueryBuilder()
 *         ->select('u')
 *         ->from('User', 'u')
 *         ->join('u.Phonenumbers', 'p', Expr\Join::WITH, 'p.is_primary = 1');
 * </code>
 *
 * @param string      $join          The relationship to join.
 * @param string      $alias         The alias of the join.
 * @param string|null $conditionType The condition type constant. Either ON or WITH.
 * @param string|null $condition     The condition for the join.
 * @param string|null $indexBy       The index for the join.
 *
 * @return QueryBuilder This QueryBuilder instance.
 */
public function join($join, $alias, $conditionType = null, $condition = null, $indexBy = null)
```

This is a doc from doctrine QueryBuilder class.